# I am receiving the following error when I try to execute my code

Tags: php

When I execute this code I see a notice :

```
Notice: Undefined offset:  3 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
Notice: Undefined offset:  6 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
Notice: Undefined offset:  9 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
Notice: Undefined offset: 12 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
Notice: Undefined offset: 15 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
Notice: Undefined offset: 18 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
Notice: Undefined offset: 21 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
Notice: Undefined offset: 24 [www/words/great_words.php, line 12]
```

the that I used :

```
<?php       
$bin = array ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$tol = 9;  
$recive_wrd = $bin[0];  
for($x=1; $x < $tol; $x++)  
{  
    $recive_wrd = $recive_wrd.$bin[$x]; // <=== Line 12  
}  
$binary[$kbin] = $recive_wrd;
?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP? I just checked and it runs fine for me.

Comment: @Joe it can't run fine, `$tot` is 9 and the highest index in `$bin` is 4. Don't know what those 3, 6, 9, ... indexes are though.

Comment: Oh, damn, don't know how that happened. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: It's ok, I approved the edit without spotting so it's my fault too!

Comment: Are any of the tags on this question legit, aside from `php` ?